# Spring Cloud Gateway : do not call service and just return status 200 on specific route

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using Spring Cloud Gateway and I have an yml file to define all my routes.

What I would like to do, is for some specific route, the gateway will not route to my service but just returns a 200 status instead.

I tried this piece of code :

```yaml
 - id: init
        uri: no://op    
        predicates: 
        - Path=/login/init
```

It seems to work fine because my route returns 200 but the service is not actually called.
However, I'm not sure this is the correct way of using no://op.
Is there a cleaner solution ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a specific response status, a [SetStatus](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/spring-cloud-gateway/gatewayfilter-factories/setstatus-factory.html) filter could be used.

As for the practice of using `uri: no://op`, it is widely recommended, but unfortunately, it works just because none of the `GatewayFilter` implementations handle the scheme `no://`, so some defaults are used for the response.